# RestTemplate Exception thrown when Authorization header begins with “Bearer”

Tags: spring, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, resttemplate

Anything other string will work for the Authorization header except anything that beings with “bearer”. The Exception that is throw is below as well as the code snippet of the RestTemplate

```
 org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);        
    httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "Bearer a3aae4e7-c612-47ef-be80-9af3d928d553");
    httpHeaders.add("Accept", "*/*");
    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    map.add("display_name", "first.last@example.com");
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:66) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my OAuth server could not resolve the bearer token, because it could not connect to the database from a bad connection string.